# Sort array of objects by one property of nested object

Tags: java, arrays

I need to compare an array of objects by one property of one of its objects property.
I am doing :

```
List<Sell> collect = sells.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Sell::getClient.name, String::compareToIgnoreCase))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It's not compiling, doesn anyone know how to do?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error? What does Shell.getClient look like?

Comment: What is Sell, Client class definitions? What is sells of which you are using stream. Provide complete code.

Comment: If you want a case insensitive `Comparator` use `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`. `String::compareToIgnoreCase` is a comparison method returning an int not a `Comparator`

Comment: It just says it can't find getClient.name. In Sell object I have a Client object which has a property name. I have the feeling that I can't use this method with property of nested object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the part of the code that causes an error

`Sell::getClient.name`

Your can create a reference to a (static or non-static) method of an arbitrary object of a particular type. A reference to the `getClient` method of any object of `Sell` type looks like this :

`Sell::getClient`

But method references are not objects and don't have members to access. With this code you are trying to access a member variable of the reference (and can't)

`Sell::getClient.name`

Also, method references are not classes so you can't get another method reference from them. You couldn't do something like that if you tried :

`Sell::getClient::getName`

Correct syntax for your particular case was provided by @mlk :

1. `x -> x.getClient().name`
2. `Sell::getClientName`  (doesn't have to be a static method)

Answer (score 3):

In order to access the nested property and sort in reversed order, I am doing as:

```
Comparator<Sell> comparator = Comparator.comparing(h -> h.getAudit().getCreatedTs());
    sells.sort(comparator.reversed());
```

Comment: This was the only way to make it work for me: I've tried
`Sell.sort((Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getAudit().getCreatedTs()).reversed());`
but kept having an error on the reversed method

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your code, or the error you are getting. So this is a guess.

I believe you want

```
class Test {

    // I assume that Client looks like this.
    static class Client {
        public String name;
    }

    // And that Sell looks like this.
    // I'm sure your Client and Sell are bigger, but this is all 
    // that matters for now. 
    static class Sell {
        public Client getClient() { return null; }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<Sell> sells = new ArrayList<>();
        sells.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getClient().name, String::compareToIgnoreCase))
    }
}
```

You want to call a method on the return of that, so you need to create an anonymous function.

Your other option would be:

```
static class Sell {
    public String getClientName() { return null; }
}
// ...
        sells.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Sell::getClientName, String::compareToIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: I agree with most of it. But if a method like `getClientName` is available, it doesn't have to be static. According to the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) you can get a "Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type"

Comment: Ah. OK fixed my anwser.