# Sort a List by nested object fields with Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a list of objects with a nested object whose fields I want to use to order that List, but I can't access the fields of that object? How can I do this with Java 8?

These fields aren't from the same type. So, the questions bwllow doesn't apply to this case:

[Sort array of objects by one property of nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753899/sort-array-of-objects-by-one-property-of-nested-object)

[Comparator.comparing(...) of a nested field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533338/comparator-comparing-of-a-nested-field)

[Java 8 Comparator keyExtractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49657284/java-8-comparator-keyextractor)

```
list.sort(Comparator
            .comparing(ListObject::getNestedObject.getField1)
            .thenComparing(ListObject::getNestedObject.getField2)
            .thenComparing(ListObject::getNestedObject.getField3));
```